# Runtime error ng-select-selection-model -

Tags: angular, select, package.json, angular-ngselect

My purpose is to use this [select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)

in my lazy load module  I do:

```
imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,    
        NgSelectModule        

    ],
    providers: []
```

The template:

```
<ng-select [items]="list" [bindLabel]="TIPE" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="tipe" (onChange)="changeValue($event)" >
            </ng-select>
```

When the user goes on this route, it prints in the console this error:

:

```
 Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model -> InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model -> InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model -> InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model -> InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ng-select-selection-model!
```

I don't understand why,anyone can help me?

Comment: We have the same problem and we don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, I imported the `NgSelectModule` at both the main application module and the component module and it was fixed.

You might also want to look at [this](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1464).

Comment: This answer helped me. I had a parent-child related components where I was loading the child component within parent. When I added the import statement in the parent, my component loaded fine.

Answer (score 2):

Do import `NgSelectModule` in your `app.module.ts` along with the component module.

Answer (score 1):

We had a different problem. We used @ng-select/ng-select": "3.7.2" and one of the third party component used the version 3.7.3.

After we updated to the same version the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while running test case.

I resolved it by importing `NgSelectModule` under `imports` block.

If you are using `NgSelectComponent` in your code for some use-case/scenario purpose then you can also declare `NgSelectComponent` under `declarations` block if needed

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [... , NgSelectModule],
        declarations: [MultiSelectCtrlComponent, NgSelectComponent],
        providers: []
    });
```

I hope it may help you or someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Only add `NgSelectModule` to `app.module.ts` and it works all across your app. This module doesn't work properly in a modal for example, because of it lazy loading.